# How do I calculate the remainder of the integer division between two numbers, using only subtraction and addition?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int num1, num2, i;
    printf("Digite o primeiro numero:");
    scanf("%d",&num1);
    printf("Digite o segundo numero:");
    scanf("%d",&num2);
    do{
        num1-num2;
        i++;
    }while (num1!=0);
    printf("O resto dessa divisao e: %d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Develop in C a program that calculates the remainder of the integer division between two numbers. Use only the operations addition and subtraction to calculate the result.

That's the question, I came up with this code, but I don't know what to do, can anyone help me?

Comment: Why have you tagged C#? Do not tag unrelated languages. This code has syntax that wouldn't even compile in C#, but it's valid C!

Comment: Hint: can you use your loop to also find `i*num2` without multiplying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think perhaps you've misunderstood what the remainder is (judging by your attempted solution). In the division 6/4, the remainder is 2. That is to say, 4 goes into 6 once, and leaves 2.

So what we can do is this:

1. Loop while num1 is bigger than (or equal to) num2
2. In the loop: Subtract num2 from num1
3. Whatever is left after the loop is the remainder.

Let's test this with 15 and 4:

```
15 - 4 = 11
11 - 4 = 7
7  - 4 = 3
```

Therefore, the remainder is 3.

As code, that looks like this:

```
int num1, num2, remainder;
num1 = 15;
num2 = 4;
remainder = num1;
while (remainder >= num2)
{
    remainder = remainder - num2;
}
printf("O resto dessa divisao e: %d\n", remainder); // prints 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea: we need to repeatedly subtract num2 from num1. However, you never set the result of that subtraction back to num1.

Instead of `num1-num2;`, you should do `num1=num1-num2;`

Furthermore: i is counting the quotient of the division, whereas the question asks for the remainder.

To do, this, we can keep *subtracting num2 from num1* **while** *num1 is greater than or equal to num2*.

```
    while (num1>=num2){
        num1=num1-num2;
    }
```

Finally, the result is stored in num1, and we can print that instead of i. In fact, we don't even need the i variable!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much to everyone who helped me, the code worked as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int num1, num2;
    printf("Digite o primeiro numero:");
    scanf("%d",&num1);
    printf("Digite o segundo numero:");
    scanf("%d",&num2);
    while (num1 >= num2){
        num1 = num1-num2;
    }
    printf("O resto dessa divisao e: %d\n", num1);
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry for my English, I'm just a Brazilian using a translator! kkkk

Comment: A few comments: 1) Always check the `scanf` return value. 2) How will your code handle negative numbers? 3) How will your code handle input that sets `num2` to zero